# Outlook 2010 Custom Quick Step Move and Reply still saves reply in Sent folder instead of the moved to folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to put customer emails into customer folders and I want the replies saved in the customer folder.  I have setup Outlook to save replies in the same folder as the message.  When I manually move an email to folder XYZ and then click reply, my reply is saved in folder XYZ as I want.  But when I use my custom quick step that moves to folder (ask user) + reply, the reply is still saved in the Sent folder.

Looks like the behind the scenes code doesn't update the email object's location before the reply triggers.  Any ideas how to create a *single* Quick Step that will move an email to a user selected folder, trigger a reply action and have the reply saved in that same moved-to folder?

Comment: Have you checked the rule details to see if you stop processing other rules?

Comment: This is a Quick Step, not a rule.  The only rule I have setup is to delay all sent emails by 1 minute.

Comment: I would suggest setting up a rule for your sent folder. If an email is from you, then have it moved to your XYZ folder.

Comment: So I have to tell Outlook where to put the sent email and then tell it where to put the original from the inbox?  I have more than 10 or 20 customers - I can't hard code a rule send to folder. I need to be asked. A bit comical that this can't work.  Am I the only one that needs to keep customer correspondence separate but include my responses in that folder?  It's looking like I just manually move the inbox email and then reply from there. At least I only have to choose the folder once... QuickStep appears to be useless for this task.

Comment: How I would do it: 1) up a group/mailing list with the emails address for the customers. Set up a rule checking if a message is FROM anyone on that address list and move it into the customer folder. 3) set up a second rule check if a message is TO anyone on that list. Once you have it all set up, the only maintenance you have to do is adding and removing address from the customer list.

Comment: I instead went with a [VBA script](http://superuser.com/questions/1067851/emails-replied-to-by-vba-script-do-not-show-reply-icon-with-purple-arrow/1067856#1067856) which now works perfectly, thanks to [IMTheNachoMan](http://superuser.com/users/456058/imthenachoman).  It would have been nice to get a QuickStep to work, though.

Comment: Yes. Agreed. Writing a script is always the best answer when it is something detailed like this.